# Transpose of a non square list of tuple in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a list of tuples like below:
e.g.

```
[(a,1), (b, 2), (b, 3), (b , 4), (c,5), (c,6)]
```

But I want to have he list of tuples or a list of list in the below way:

```
[(a,1), (b,2,3,4) , (c, 5, 6)]
```

could not understand how to achieve this in Python 3.7. Any help will be really appreciated!

Regards
Bineeta

Comment: "_But I want to have [...]_" seems like you have some code producing an undesired output and you want to fix it. If you don't provide the code, we can only suggest you how to to go from the first to the second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [("a",1), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("b" , 4), ("c",5), ("c",6)]
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data:
    result[k].append(v)

print([tuple([k] + v) for k, v in result.items()])
```

---

using `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
data = [("a",1), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("b" , 4), ("c",5), ("c",6)]
result = {}
for k, v in data:
    result.setdefault(k, [k]).append(v)

print(list(map(tuple, result.values())))
```

**Output:**

```
[('a', 1), ('c', 5, 6), ('b', 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: your output is a different order from what would be achieved on py 3.7

Comment: Sorry I do not have py3.7 to maintain the order in the dict

Answer (score 0):

If your list is always sorted, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [('a',1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('b' , 4), ('c',5), ('c',6)]

result = [(k, *map(itemgetter(1), g)) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]
print(result)
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2, 3, 4), ('c', 5, 6)]
```

If it isn't always sorted, you can sort it beforehand by applying [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
[(k, *map(itemgetter(1), g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))]
```